# Unable to load service index for source: UrlBlockedExtended

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm doing poc and facing below error while searching package for Sharepoint  PnP in visual studio 2017

```
[Nuget.org] Unable to load service index for source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Response status code does not indicate 
success: 403 (UrlBlockedExtended)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Before you ask a question make sure to read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Can you provide any further information about your project and attach code in text form of what you have done?